# MySQL sum ranking, group by genre, limit 10

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit, database-performance

I have MySQL tables like these and I would like to calculate the TOP10 for each genre:

- rankings_2016 (trackId, genreId, ranking, timestamp)
- genres (genreId, genreName)
- tracks (trackId, trackName, genreId)
- artists (artistId, artistName)
- artists_tracks (artistId, trackId)

I would like to get TOP10 rankings for each genre, for every track and for every artist.

A track or an artist could have up to 2 genres. Ranking could be the same. Just to get the idea with LIMIT 2:

```
  genreId | trackId | ranking
 ---------------------------------
   0         1111      100
   0         2222       99
   1         1111      100
   1         2222       99

  genreId | artistId | ranking
 ---------------------------------
   0         1111      100
   0         2222       99
   1         1111      100
   1         2222       99
```

The only solution I found is getting everything in a table and then LIMIT 10 in the page, but it's killing my database in terms of size (I have limited resources).

For the tracks I wrote this:

```
SELECT trackId, genreId, @newRank := SUM(ranking) as ranking
FROM rankings_2016
WHERE timestamp >= ( select unix_timestamp('2016-01-01') )
AND timestamp <= ( select unix_timestamp('2016-12-31') )
GROUP BY trackId, genreId
```

For the artists:

```
SELECT artistId, genreId, @newRank := SUM(a1.ranking) as ranking
FROM rankings_2016 a1
LEFT JOIN artists_tracks a2
ON a1.trackId = a2.trackId
WHERE timestamp >= ( select unix_timestamp('2016-01-01') )
AND timestamp <= ( select unix_timestamp('2016-12-31') )
GROUP BY artistId, genreId
```

Thank all in advance for your hints.

---

## UPDATE

The logic in general (and accepted reply) requires good indexes and performant server.

ARTISTS in my case failed with error 500 unless I increased CPU.
In general replacing LEFT with INNER saves 1 second.

Comment: If performance is an issue and the rankings don't change frequently, consider pre-calculating the answer.

Comment: Rankings change daily: my actual queries pre-fill some tables with all the results wasting hundred thousands rows daily. How can I limit to 20 directly at pre-filling stage?

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the `timestamp` table. Can't think of anything else that could be slowing down these simple queries.

Comment: performance is OK, size is KO: I would like to get TOP10 rankings for each genre, for every track and for every artist. thx

Comment: Maybe this is solved, but if you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thx for the tip: i already created a SQLfiddle and it works well with a dozen datas. But, since there are several ways to write an SQL statement and this particular one generates error 500 on a powerful testing environment with a hundred thousand datas, it comes up that it's not the best one. If we look for just one answer, it is. If we look for an answer that actually works, this one won't work.

Comment: There is no need for a subquery to evaluate a constant:  `( select unix_timestamp('2016-01-01') ` --> `unix_timestamp('2016-01-01')`.  If you still have problems, I will look deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a correlated count subquery to rank order the rankings by Artist / Track / Genre groupings. Then use this *rank* calculated column in outer query to filter for top 10 per grouping:

**Artist Ranking** *(top 10 rankings per artist and genre)*

```
SELECT main.artistId, main.genreId, main.ranking
FROM
 (
   SELECT a.artistId, r.genreId, r.ranking,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rankings_2016 subr
           LEFT JOIN artists_tracks suba ON subr.trackId = suba.trackId
           WHERE suba.artistId = a.artistId
           AND subr.genreId = r.genreId
           AND subr.ranking >= r.ranking) AS rn
   FROM rankings_2016 r
   LEFT JOIN artists_tracks a ON r.trackId = a.trackId
   WHERE r.timestamp BETWEEN ( select unix_timestamp('2016-01-01') )
                         AND ( select unix_timestamp('2016-12-31') ) 
 ) AS main

WHERE main.rn <= 10
```

**Track Ranking** *(top 10 rankings per track and genre)*

```
SELECT main.trackId, main.genreId, main.ranking
FROM
 (
   SELECT r.trackId, r.genreId, r.ranking,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rankings_2016 subr               
           WHERE subr.genreId = r.genreId
           AND subr.trackId = r.trackId
           AND subr.ranking >= r.ranking) AS rn
   FROM rankings_2016 r
   WHERE r.timestamp BETWEEN ( select unix_timestamp('2016-01-01') )
                         AND ( select unix_timestamp('2016-12-31') ) 
 ) AS main

WHERE main.rn <= 10
```

Comment: Thank u for the support. I think in the 2nd query u meant // "WHERE" subr.genreId = r.genreId // instead of "AND" // However I was unable to perform both because they timeout with error 500. I was able instead to pack the one for TRACKS I included in the EDIT, which performs well in 3", but if I LEFT JOIN  artists_tracks it times out as well

Comment: What does your MySQL console/workbench give? 500 is a web error. Possibly you have quite a bit of data and webpage times out. And your update is the other option in MySQL using @variables. Other RDMS's use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function. This correlated subquery would work in any SQL-compliant database.